# Jquery "cannot read propery 'id' of null" when tracking event.pageX+Y

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with creating a web applet that tracks the user's mouse pointer and interacts with div elements on click.

Works fine until when I add a new section above the applet. When I try to click on anything inside the app section on any of the targetable divs I get:

> Uncaught TypeError:   Cannot read property 'id' of null demo.js:27
>
> (anonymous function) demo.js:27
>
> x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
>
> v.handle jquery.min.js:5

When I remove the new section from the top of the page everything works fine though.

http://jsfiddle.net/gv8qv43b/

This fiddle recreates the error but it does so with or without the additional section. Which is also weird.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#phone").css('display', 'none');

    $("#outer").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#phone").fadeIn('fast', 0);
    });

    $("#outer").mousemove(function (event) {

        var parentOffset = $("#outer").offset();
        var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;

        var phone = $("#phone");

        relX = relX - (phone.width() / 2);
        relY = relY - (phone.height() / 2);

        phone.css("left", relX + 'px');
        phone.css("top", relY + 'px');
    });

    $("#phone").click(function (event) {
        var phone = $("#phone");
        phone.css('display', 'none');
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        console.log('Clicked: ' + elem.id);
        phone.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $("#outer").mouseleave(function () {
        $('#phone').fadeOut('fast', 0);
    });
});
```

```css
#top-bg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: center center no-repeat;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#top-bg .landingtext {
    width: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 15%;
}
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: center center no-repeat;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#thing1 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 112px;
    margin-left: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
}
#thing2 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 265px;
    margin-left: 195px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#thing3 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 410px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 252px;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#thing4 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 475px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 155px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
#thing5 {
    right: 50%;
    top: 400px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 205px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
#thing6 {
    right: 50%;
    top: 400px;
    margin-right: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 112px;
    height: 205px;
    background-color: grey;
}
#thing7 {
    right: 50%;
    top: 400px;
    margin-right: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 112px;
    height: 205px;
    background-color: purple;
}
#thing8 {
    right: 50%;
    top: 397px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 112px;
    height: 208px;
    background-color: pink;
}
#phone {
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 381px;
    background-color: #2858b9;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: crosshair;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <!-- Section: intro -->
    <section id="top-bg">
        <div class="landingtext">
             <h1>Make paper come to life</h1>

             <h3>with Interactive print by ori</h3>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: intro -->
    <!-- Section: demo -->
    <section id="examples">
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="phone"></div>
            <div id="thing1">Thing 1</div>
            <div id="thing2">Thing 2</div>
            <div id="thing3">Thing 3</div>
            <div id="thing4">Thing 4</div>
            <div id="thing5">Thing 5</div>
            <div id="thing6">Thing 6</div>
            <div id="thing7">Thing 7</div>
            <div id="thing8">Thing 8</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Section: demo -->
</body>
```

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint()` is returning `null`.

Comment: Is there any reason you're tracking the position throughout the page, and not just on mouseover/mouseout of the certain elements?

Comment: Try substituting `event.target` for `document.elementFromPoint()`  http://jsfiddle.net/gv8qv43b/3/

Comment: @Jhecht How do I do track the mouse only in the key element??

Comment: With jquery, it's fairly easily. If I can assume that each item you want to track the mouse on has a class of 'mouse', then in jquery: `$('.mouse').on('mouseover,function(){...}).on('mouseout',function(){...})`, replacing the `function(){...}` with whatever you need code-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes to http://jsfiddle.net/gv8qv43b/4/ :

- `pointer-events: none;` on `#phone` so that when you click, it goes through `#phone` to the element behind it.
- `$("#outer > div").click()` so only clicking on the `#thing`s has an effect.  (`#phone` is included in the selector, but as above, it can't receive `click`s.)
- `var elem = this;`.  let the browser do the heavy lifting and figure out what you clicked on.  no need for `elementFromPoint()`.